# wxPython show image certain amount of time

Tags: python

I am using code in wxPython to show images.
I created a screen with 2 panels, one left and right. 
In one of the panels (randomly chosen), I want do display an image for exactly 150ms.
How can I program this? I am relatively new to Python, and I don't find any clear way on the internet.

My code for now (without the 150ms):

```
    import wxversion
    wxversion.select("3.0")
    import wx
    import random
    import timeclass Screen_1(wx.Dialog):
    ri  = 0
    def __init__(self,parent,id,title):
    wx.Dialog.__init__(self,parent,id,title,size=(400,300)) 
    self.randomImage = random.randrange(1,3) 
    self.randomSlot = random.randrange(1,3)

    Screen_1.ri = self.randomImage

    if(self.randomSlot == 1):
        self.side = 'Left'
    else:
        self.side = 'Right'


    file = open('User.txt','a')
    panel_left = wx.Panel(self,11,(-1,-1),(200,200)) 
    self.picture_left = wx.StaticBitmap(panel_left)

    font = wx.Font(13,wx.DEFAULT,wx.NORMAL,wx.BOLD)
    panel_centre = wx.Panel(self,12,(200,70),(10,100))
    msg = wx.StaticText(panel_centre,-1,'+',size=(10,100))
    msg.SetFont(font)

    panel_right = wx.Panel(self,13,(210,0),(200,200)) 
    self.picture_right = wx.StaticBitmap(panel_right)

    **self.imageName = 'im_'+str(self.randomImage)+'.png'**

    if self.randomSlot == 1:
        self.picture_left.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(self.imageName))
    else:
        self.picture_right.SetBitmap(wx.Bitmap(self.imageName))
    wx.FutureCall(1000,self.Destroy)
    self.Centre()
    self.ShowModal()

def OnClick(self,event):
    self.Close()
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
def OnTimeUp(self,e):
   #change images
   self.timer.Start(15,oneShot=True) # if you want to call it again in 15 ms
def StartTimer(self):
   self.timer = wx.Timer()
   self.timer.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER,self.OnTimeUp)
   self.timer.Start(15,oneShot=True)
```

something like that ... although 15ms is very fast ...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! But how do I implement this in my code, how do I link it? What about the "e"? Sorry if this sounds noobish.

Comment: you put these 2 methods in your class ... then you call the `myClassInstance.StartTimer()` to start it. what about the e? ...

Comment: I don't recognize the "e" in "def OnTimeUp(self,e) anywhere else in my or your code. What does it define?

Comment: the event that is passed as an argument to all wx.EventListeners.. in this instance I dont need it ... but python will crash if I dont accept it ...